# how to navigate an android from one page to another?

Tags: android, navigation

i have 5 layouts and buttons that navigate from one to another live this: a-c, a-b, c-d, d-e.
I only can navigate from a to b anc c. I put the same code to the others but application stops.

Comment: Need a lot more information.  How are you displaying the different layouts?  Different Activities?  Fragments?  Show the code you're using to change from one to another also.

Comment: Please post the log cat logs

Comment: If different activities, check if you have all your activities in your manifest first. Next, show the log at least or give code examples.

Comment: One whole week and no responses. You sure you need the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *layouts* are *Activities*; All you need to do is set button click listeners and call corresponding activity in listener block.

For instance; in **ActivityA** (onCreate() method)

```
btnStartB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartB);
btnStartB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

you will need to do same for btnStartC in ActivityA, btnStartD in ActivityC and btnStartE in ActivityD. Try debugging and figure out where it stops.